# How can I replace only ONE line break using a Javascript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text:

I need to replace one line break (`\r\n`) with "`<br>`" and when there are more than one line break replace it with one break.

For example:

```
LINE1 
LINE2

LINE3
LINE4



LINE3
LINE4
```

Becomes:

```
LINE1<br>LINE2
LINE3<br>LINE4
LINE5<br>LINE6
```

Answer:

```
.replace(/([^\r\n])\r\n([^\r\n])/g, '$1<br>$2').replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "\r\n");
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This is really trivial and most likely already explained somewhere on stack overflow. Have you tried google?

Comment: Guys, don't be so smart, it can spoil your weekend! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str
   .replace(/\r\n([^\r\n])/g, "<br>$1")
   .replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "\r\n");
```

Comment: replace(/(\r\n)+/g, "<br>") that replaces all line breaks in my text for <br> where I have more then one line break I need to repace it with one line breack (not <br>)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: See my updated answer. It's tested in my console, it works/

Comment: The result I got in node: LINE1<br>LINE2<br>LINE3<br>LINE4<br>LINE3<br>LINE4 - one line

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: What's the difference between what you need and this?

Comment: I need line break between LINE3 and LINE4

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple regular expression:

```
str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "<br>");
```

- `[\r\n]+` matches either a plain newline or carriage return followed by a newline which occurs at least once and replaces it with the `<br>`
- the `g` modifier tells it to match more than just once

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something that is tolerant of different line break combinations:

```
str = str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "<br>");
```

This will match whether there's just CRs, just LFs or any combination of them and it will match any contiguous sequence of them and replace it with `<br>`.  The "g" flag tells it to replace all such sequences in the string.